# SQL to retrieve thickness values with small variance

Tags: sql, sql-server

How do I structure an SQL statement that selects a group of very similar objects? Essentially, the problem statement can boil down to `select x number of objects` whose values vary by v within a given range.

For example, I have data of some substrates that have a thickness associated with it as below:

```
╔════════════════════╗
║ SubstID  Thickness ║
╠════════════════════╣
║ Subst01    690     ║
║ Subst02    710     ║
║ Subst03    695     ║
║ Subst04    692     ║
║ Subst05    715     ║
║ Subst06    699     ║
║ Subst07    700     ║
║ Subst08    702     ║
║ Subst09    690     ║
║ Subst10    690     ║
║ Subst11    701     ║
╚════════════════════╝
```

I would like to query the data to get sets of `x number of substrates` that are within a certain range of thickness, e.g. 690 and 710 and also vary by no more than v, e.g. v=4.

Using the numbers above, this  should yield the following possibilities, if x is 3:

```
Subst01(690),Subst04(692),Subst09(690)
Subst01(690),Subst04(692),Subst10(690)
Subst01(690),Subst09(690),Subst10(690)
Subst04(692),Subst09(690),Subst10(690)
Subst06(699),Subst07(700),Subst08(702)
...
Subst06(699),Subst07(700),Subst11(701)
Subst06(699),Subst08(702),Subst11(701)
Subst07(700),Subst08(702),Subst11(701)
```

There are tens of thousands of substrates so comparison time is an issue. I can do this in a programming language, but would prefer if there is an easy solution in SQL.

Comment: What happened to `Subst03    695` in your example?

Comment: There may well be SQL Server-specific enhancements that allow something like this, but in general SQL is not designed to let the presence of some row in a result set influence the presence of another row in that result set.  So I think the only way to get these results for sets of size x is to "hardcode" it using x-1 self-joins, which will probably be pretty slow for x >= 4 or so.

Comment: @ikrabbe, I don't believe 695 fits in any set of 3's that varies by 4. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
select * 
from table t1
join table t2 on t1.substid < t2.substid
join table t3 on t2.substid < t3.substid
where abs(t1.thickness - t2.thickness) <= 3 and
      abs(t1.thickness - t3.thickness) <= 3 and
      abs(t2.thickness - t3.thickness) <= 3
```

Comment: Really elegant way of solving this problem ! (Still, does not adapt automatically to x <> 3) 
I was wondering : wouldn't it be more efficient to put all the conditions of the `WHERE` clause in the `ON` clauses ? I mean that : `SELECT * 
FROM table t1
JOIN table t2 
 ON t1.substid < t2.substid
 AND abs(t1.thickness - t2.thickness) <= 3
JOIN table t3 
 ON t2.substid < t3.substid
 AND abs(t1.thickness - t3.thickness) <= 3 
 AND abs(t2.thickness - t3.thickness) <= 3`

Comment: Probably it will be the same. We should look on execution plans.

Comment: I think the where clause is executed at the end, whereas the conditions in the ON clause are executed directly, so it saves some computations, was just wondering anyway that's no big deal.

Comment: No it is not true. Engine can decide to do right the opposite way, first filtering then joining. It is only conceptual ordering first from then where etc. In reality engine can decide to shuffle those ordering of executions.

Comment: The idea is very good, however, I have over 75,000 records with close values and after 3 hours SQL Server is still running this query. I may have to change my requirements and do this in a programming language.

Comment: Do you have index on thickness colum? On substid fk columns?

Answer (score 1):

As @j_random_hacker mentioned, SQL doesn't easily do *x*-number of self-joins, but you can use some XML Path trickery to get a concatenated list of objects within the variance. Unfortunately, this doesn't always force the resultset of SimilarObjects to be 3.

```
Declare @var int=4
Declare @x int=3

;with VarSubstrates as (
    Select SubstID,Thickness,Thickness+@var as ThicknessMin,Thickness-@var as ThicknessMax
    From Substrates
)
Select vo.SubstID,vo.Thickness,stuff(subs.SimilarObjects,1,1,'') as SimilarObjects
From VarSubstrates vo
Outer Apply (
    Select Top (@x) ','+vi.SubstID+'('+cast(vi.Thickness as varchar)+')'
    From VarSubstrates vi
    Where vi.Thickness Between vo.ThicknessMax and vo.ThicknessMin
    For XML Path('')
) subs(SimilarObjects)
```

Output:

```
SubstID Thickness  SimilarObjects
Subst01 690        Subst01(690),Subst04(692),Subst09(690)
Subst02 710        Subst02(710)
Subst03 695        Subst03(695),Subst04(692),Subst06(699)
Subst04 692        Subst01(690),Subst03(695),Subst04(692)
...
```

Comment: If this method (or something similar) meets the OP's needs, then it has greater scope for performance improvement (with an index on `Thickness`).

Answer (score 0):

How does this work for you. I made some temp tables for the testing. I know its not exactly the format you want out, but i figured it was good

```
Declare @Dist as varchar(10)
Declare @Sets as varchar(10)
Declare @Ct as int
Declare @SQL as NVARCHAR(MAX)

Set @Dist = 4
Set @Sets = 3

select 'Subst01'as 'SubstID' ,    '690' as 'Thickness'
into #temp
union select 'Subst02',    '710'
union select 'Subst03',    '695'
union select 'Subst04',    '692'
union select 'Subst05',    '715'
union select 'Subst06',    '699'
union select 'Subst07',    '700'
union select 'Subst08',    '702'
union select 'Subst09',    '690'
union select 'Subst10',    '690'
union select 'Subst11',    '701'

Set @Ct = 1
Set @SQL = 'Select '

While @Ct < @Sets +1
Begin

Set @SQL = @SQL + 's' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),@Ct) + '.Substid , ' + 's' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),@Ct) + '.Thickness ,'

Set @Ct = @Ct +  1
Print @Ct

end

Set @SQL = LEFT(@SQL,Len(@SQL) -1) + CHAR(13) + 'From #temp s1'

Set @Ct = 2

While @Ct < @Sets +1
Begin

Set @SQL = @SQL  + CHAR(13) +  'inner join #temp s' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),@Ct)  + CHAR(13)
            +  'on s' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),@Ct) + '.thickness between s1.thickness -  ' + @dist
                                                            + ' and s1.thickness + '+ @Dist

Set @Ct = @Ct +  1
Print @Ct

end


print @SQL
exec sp_executesql @SQL
```